# AWS EventBridge - reading event archive

Tags: aws-event-bridge

Does anyone know if there's an API for reading events archived using the EventBridge archiving feature?

We're aiming to do event replays but the out-of-the-box event replay feature won't work for us as we need to preserve time order of the events. As a workaround, I'm wondering if there's an option to do this manually by trawling the event archive and then raising the events in order